# Como ordenar vetor de objetos verificando um atributo?

Tags: javascript

Consigo ordenar uma lista simples usando o método `sort` Veja:

```js
var distances = [15, 18, 27, 29, 5, 3]

distances.sort(function(a, b){
   return a-b;
});

console.log(distances);
```

Porém gostaria gostaria de ordenar uma lista de objetos baseado no atributo `distance`, por exemplo:

```
var listDistances = [
    {distance: 857, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}, 
    {distance: 26, location: {lat: 18.246, lnt:16.4552}},
    {distance: 740, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}
];
```

Desta forma o resultado seria:

```
var listDistances = [        
    {distance: 26, location: {lat: 18.246, lnt:16.4552}},
    {distance: 740, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}},
    {distance: 857, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}, 
];
```

Como ordenar vetor de objetos verificando o atributo `distance`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

É a mesma coisa

```js
var listDistances = [
    {distance: 857, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}, 
    {distance: 26, location: {lat: 18.246, lnt:16.4552}},
    {distance: 740, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}
];


listDistances.sort(function(a, b){
   return a.distance - b.distance;
});

console.log(listDistances);
```

Comment: Jesus, acho que tinha feito alguma coisa errado então! Vlw... agora deu! =)

Answer (score 3):

Outra sugestão é utilizar a lib lodash. Ela tem diversas funções em javascript que fazem o trabalho "duro". Por exemplo, realizar esta operação de orderar seria simples assim:

```
var listDistances = [
    {distance: 857, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}, 
    {distance: 26, location: {lat: 18.246, lnt:16.4552}},
    {distance: 740, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}
];

_.sortBy(listDistances, ['distance']);
```

Se quisesse ordenar por um sub item:

```
var listDistances = [
    {distance: 857, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}, 
    {distance: 26, location: {lat: 18.246, lnt:16.4552}},
    {distance: 740, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}
];

_.sortBy(listDistances, ['location.lat']);
```

Se quisesse ordenar por vários campos:

Se quisesse ordenar por um sub item:

```
var listDistances = [
    {distance: 857, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}, 
    {distance: 26, location: {lat: 18.246, lnt:16.4552}},
    {distance: 740, location: {lat: 15.246, lnt:16.4552}}
];

_.sortBy(listDistances, ['distance', 'location.lat']);
```

Muito simples. O link da lib: https://lodash.com/